# Can Firebase functions deploy only to emulator?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to deploy only to the emulator to speed up the development process?  It currently takes about a minute to deploy functions to the Firebase server.

I add, then update a function of some sort in index.ts, such as:

```
export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  console.log("hello");
  response.send("Hello from firebase!");
});
```

I then save the function in VS Code, while running the emulator.  Though the firestore.rules file updates and shows in the emulator console when it's been changed, the index.ts file does not.  The functions update on both the emulator and the Firebase Functions again only when I enter "firebase deploy --only functions".  But it takes about a minute, which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Bro did you get the solution for this issue. If you get please share

Comment: Yes, it was answered best by Frank below.  The emulator updates automatically when you save your functions.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the local emulator as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator), it should pick up your local Cloud Functions already. It should even automatically pick up any changes you make to the local Cloud Functions code.

If you've follow these steps and it doesn't work, can you edit your question to show exactly what you've done?

Comment: So I discovered the issue.  I'm using Flutter and needed to call `  FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
`

Comment: Awesome. Great to hear you found it. 

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered the issue. I'm using Flutter and needed to call `FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);`
There are other emulator use functions and they go with separate emulators ("Auth" for example).  Once I save the javascript file I can see the emulated function using the new file.